# Method overloading -Distinguish between Nullable DateTime and String Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, nullable

I have one interface like this

```
public interface IPrice
{
    IEnumerable<Price> GetPrice(string portalShopName);

    IEnumerable<Price> GetPrice(DateTime? lastRunDate);

}
```

In this case how can i access second method with a nullable DateTime

Comment: `GetPrice((DateTime?)null)`

Comment: i will go with PetSerAl answer..it is working

Answer (score 1):

As *PetSerAl* has put in comments, you can *cast* like this:

```
  IPrice price = ...

  var result = price.GetPrice((DateTime?)null);
```

However, I suggest implementing an *extension method* for *hiding* such a cast:

```
  public static class PriceExtensions {
    //TODO: may be "GetDefaultPrice" is a better name for the method
    public static IEnumerable<Price> GetPrice(this IPrice price) {
      if (null == price)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("price");

      return price.GetPrice((DateTime?)null);
    }
  }
```

And so you can put it

```
  IPrice price = ...

  var result = price.GetPrice();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first implement your interface in a class like this:

```
public class testClass : IPrice
{

    public IEnumerable<Price> GetPrice(string portalShopName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Price> GetPrice(DateTime? lastRunDate)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can call `GetPrice` in this way:

```
testClass tst = new testClass();
tst.GetPrice((DateTime?)null);
tst.GetPrice((string) null);
```

Comment: Methodname is same.how to distinguish between string with null value and datetime with null value

Comment: @vmb .. Well when you send a parameter as `DateTime` it will call that method with `DateTime` and when you pass a `string` it will call the string version.